# Does node_load() function prevent multiple loading of the same node?

Tags: nodes

In some cases, for example page where a lot of block are loading the same current node in one request it could be useful to load node just once for every block. Once I read somewhere this is default functionality for node_load() function.

Is it really true, or do I have to workaround that by myslef (store node as global variable or something like that)? Documentation says nothing about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, node data is statically cached per request, if the requests are for *un-revisioned* nodes. No, you don't need to do the caching yourself.

The cache read/write happens in [`NodeController::load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/DrupalDefaultEntityController%3A%3Aload/7) if you're interested in what's going on behind the scenes.